# Using elements from different numpy arrays contained in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list such as:

```
a=[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
```

now, I want to accsess e.g. each element of each list with the same index and perform something with that. Lets say mean of the value with the same index of each array.

I can accsess each list index with e.g.

```
a[0][2]
```

resulting in 3. But the following does not work

```
meanedValues=[None]*3
for j in range(len(a[0])):                           #given all arrays have the same length
     meanedValues[j]=mean(a[:][j])
```

Results in meaning each array in itselve instead of each element of the same index from each list.

and

```
meanedValues=[None]*3
for j in range(len(a[0])):                           #given all arrays have the same length
     meanedValues[j]=mean(a[:](0,j))
```

returns: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Why is that a list, and not a 2D array?

Comment: Good point. This comes due to multible processing in a differnt function. I simplyfied this to the minimum. I will see if I can change that. Thanks for the hint. Edit: seeing the answeres it does seem simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a 2d numpy array which natively supports your required operations:

```
a= np.array([np.array([1,2,3]),
             np.array([4,5,6]),
             np.array([7,8,9])])

print(a)

>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])

# get 2nd values
print(a[:, 1])

>>> array([2, 5, 8])


# get mean values
print(np.mean(a, axis=0))

>>>  array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
```

Answer (score 1):

*Given all arrays have the same length*, you can convert the list to a 2d array, then take average over axis 0:

```
np.asarray(a).mean(0)
# array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
```